# How to create multiple tableview cell using Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am creating `accordion tableview` cell using `iOS storyboard`. Here I have maintaining two `tableview custom cell classes` and `cells` on single storyboard within single tableview.

Now my problem is after selected the row based on `plist` storage It will expand (adding) additional rows at under the selected two. I need to use separate tableview cell for selected tableview cell `(parent cell)` and expandable cell `(child cell)`. By my below code parent and child cell are showing and referring same cells(thats is parent only. So I cant differentiate UI for parent and child.

Need to modify below my logic.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *dic=[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([dic valueForKey:@"SubItems"])
    {
        NSArray *arr=[dic valueForKey:@"SubItems"];
        BOOL isTableExpanded=NO;

        for(NSDictionary *subitems in arr )
        {
            NSInteger index=[self.itemsInTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:subitems];
            isTableExpanded=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isTableExpanded) break;
        }

        if(isTableExpanded)
        {
            [self CollapseRows:arr];
        }
        else
        {
            // NEED TO ADD SECOND CELL HERE
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arrCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in arr)
            {
                [arrCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.itemsInTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [self.main_tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okeh. And where is your cellForRowAtIndexPath function?

Comment: Check above I have updated give me one Idea!@Jorn Buitink

Comment: `[CellIdentifier_one isEqualToString:@"Cell_One"]` is always equal to `YES`?

Comment: [CellIdentifier_one isEqualToString:@"Cell_One"] is always true.

Comment: adding a screen shot of UI (what you are expecting) may help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In following code I created multilevel of expandable `UITableView` using `.plist` file.

Read Data from `.plist` file

```
NSDictionary *dTmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]];
self.arrayOriginal = [dTmp valueForKey:@"Objects"];

self.arForTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.arForTable addObjectsFromArray:self.arrayOriginal];
```

Code for `UITableView` Delegates and Datasource.

```
   // Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.arForTable count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
        NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

        BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
            NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
            if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
        }

        if(isAlreadyInserted) {
            [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
        } else {
            NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
    }
}

-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{

    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
            [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
        }

        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.tblForCollapse deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                                    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]
                                                    ]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }
}
```

[Download the sample code from here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/Cell%20Min%20max/cellMaxMinDemo%202.zip/download)

**Output**

[image]

May this help to fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Give me two min I am checking!@Nimit Parekh

Comment: Its really great I have one doubt from your source code. There sections you have used but I dont want to section how can I remove? only two process parent cell if parent cell have a subitems need to expand and show child cell. Both cells UI need to differentiate.plz tel me@Nimit Parekh

Comment: @Apple_Ajay Man, I am not using header that's why I am passing `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns 1; I use directly rows if you don't want to child then just go to the `.plist` file and add one object and no child then it's self not expanding the parent controller.

Comment: How can I seperate two UI's thats my problem. Could you please check my above image post @Nimit Parekh

Comment: Parent and child UI not showing different both are same. Hocan I seperate that logics I dont know that is my plm also. Your code and mine both same the thing need to make different UI for parent and child.@Nimit Parekh

Comment: @Apple_Ajay you need to add some flag value once click on parent controller that time flag value enable and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you just verify and apply according cell returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97935/discussion-between-nimit-parekh-and-apple-ajay).

Comment: See the person @Nimit Parekh helped lot give some award to him stack overflow!Thank you bro.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to design two different table cell views, and instantiate either one in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, depending on if it's a sub-item or a not.

Pretty much

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    id item = self.itemsInTable[indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (item[@"isSubItem"]) {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"subItemCell"];

    } else {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"normalCell"];
    }

    // ...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Give me two min I am checking!

Answer (score 0):

DSNestedAccordion does nested tableViews very well. Have a look [here](https://github.com/deepan/DSNestedAccordion)